# what is Gridsearch.cv_results_ , could any explain all the things in that i.e mean_test_score etc .?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am doing hyperparameter tuning with `GridSearchCV` for Decision Trees. I have fit the model and I am trying to find what does exactly `Gridsearch.cv_results_` gives. I have read the documentation but still its not clear. Could anyone explain this attribute?

my code is below :

```
depth={"max_depth":[1,5,10,50,100,500,1000],
       "min_samples_split":[5,10,100,500]}       

DTC=DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight="balanced")

DTC_Grid=GridSearchCV(DTC,param_grid=depth , cv=3, scoring='roc_auc')
DTC_Bow=DTC_Grid.fit(xtrain_bow,ytrain_bow)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

DTC_Bow.cv_results_ returns a dictionary of all the evaluation metrics from the gridsearch. To visualize it properly, you can do

```
pd.DataFrame(DTC_Bow.cv_results_)
```

In your case, this should return a dataframe with 28 rows (7 choices for `max_depth` times 4 choices for `min_samples_split`). Each row of this dataframe gives the gridsearch metrics for one combination of these two parameters. Remember the goal of a gridsearch is to select which combination of parameters will have the best performance metrics. This is the purpose of `cv_results_`.

You should have one column called `param_max_depth` and another called `param_min_samples_leaf` referencing the value of the parameter for each row. The combination of two is summarized as a dictionary in the column `params`.

Now to the metrics. Default value for `return_train_score` was `True` up until now but they will change it to `False` in version 0.21. If you want the train metrics, set it to `True`. But usually, what you are interested in are the test metrics.

The main column is `mean_test_score`. This is the average of columns `split_0_test_score, split_1_test_score, split_2_test_score` (because you are doing a 3 fold split in your gridsearch). If you do `DTC_Bow.best_score_` this will return the max value of the column `mean_test_score`. Column `rank_test_score` ranks all parameter combinations by the values of `mean_test_score`.

You might also want to look at `std_test_score` which is the standard deviation of `split_0_test_score, split_1_test_score, split_2_test_score`. This might be of interest if you want to see how consistently your set of parameters is performing on your hold-out data.

As mentioned, you can have the metrics on the train set as well provided you set `return_train_score = True`.

Finally, there are also time columns, that tell you how much time it took for each row. It measures how much time it took to train the model (`mean_fit_time, std_fit_time`) and to evaluate it (`mean_score_time, std_score_time`). This is just a FYI, usually, unless time is a bottleneck, you would not really look at these metrics.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, a bit late to the party but this helped. I was wondering though what the test_score reflects? 
I get decent test_scores in every fold but still my accuracy stays very low, thanks!